How to force a model to use a variable
I have data for train a binary classification model.
set.seed(1)
n <- 20
dat <- cbind.data.frame(target=as.factor(sample(0:1,n,T)),
                        price=round(rnorm(n)+1000,2),
                        var1=sample(1:n),
                        var2=round(rnorm(n),2),
                        var3=round(rnorm(n),2)) 

.
   target   price var1  var2  var3
1       1 1001.03    5 -0.95  1.16
2       0 1000.21   13 -0.02 -0.45
3       0  999.49   11  1.20  1.95
4       0 1000.95    7  0.71  0.86
5       1 1001.49   20 -0.44  1.07
6       0  999.45   10  0.78 -1.76
7       1  998.78   12 -1.64 -0.77
8       1  998.23    8  0.67  0.12

I would like to force my model to take into account the variable price that I specify in every decision it makes.
I'll explain with an example what I mean.
Let's say I'm using a random forest model made up of rules, in which case I would like each rule to have a price variable within it.
These are good rules because each rule has a variable price
 price<=1001.49 & var1>0.105                           
 var2<=0.12 & price>1001.03 & var3>-0.025             
 price<=998.23 & price>=997.23

These are bad rules, I wish there weren’t such rules in the model
var3<=0.57 & var3>0.105                            
var2<=0.12 & var2>-1.005 & var3>-0.025               
var1<=6.5

I understand that I cannot influence the model itself, but perhaps I can somehow change the variables in the dataset to ultimately force the model to force the use of the price variable in every decision.
As a test, you can use this code that extracts rules from a trained random forest model.
library(inTrees)
library(randomForest)
rules <- randomForest(target~., dat, ntree=20) |> 
          RF2List() |> 
          extractRules(dat) |> 
          unique() |> 
          getRuleMetric(dat[,-1], dat$target) |> 
          pruneRule(dat[,-1], dat$target) |> 
          buildLearner(dat[,-1], dat$target)

.
presentRules(rules, colnames(dat[,-1]))

    len freq   err condition                                pred
[1,] "2" "0.35" "0" "var1<=15.5 & var2<=-0.05"               "1" 
[2,] "3" "0.2"  "0" "var1<=13.5 & var2>-0.05 & var3<=-0.315" "0" 
[3,] "1" "0.1"  "0" "var2>1.255"                             "1" 
[4,] "2" "0.1"  "0" "var1>17 & var2>-1.55"                   "1" 
[5,] "1" "0.1"  "0" "var3<=-0.16"                            "0" 
[6,] "2" "0.1"  "0" "var2>-0.05 & var3>0.49"                 "0" 
[7,] "1" "0.05" "0" "Else"                                   "1" 

As you can see at this stage, the model refuses to use variable price in its rules. But the specifics of my task mean that I don’t need rules that don’t use price.
To summarize, my question sounds like this:
How can I change my dataset to force the model to use price in each of its rules?

This hack might work.
Random forests sample columns, right? Then I would just extend the dataset by adding tens (or hundreds or thousands) of copies of price column.
